# Handle device lock and screen timeout

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

In my application, I want to show the application's lock screen when user lock the phone and unlock it and I don't want to implement this feature when the display goes off and on (screen timeout).

We can use `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF/ Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON` to show the application's lock screen when user lock the phone and unlock it. But this could lock the app even when screen display goes off and on which I don't want to.

Do anybody have any idea about this? I mean how not to show the application lock screen when screen display goes off and on?